How to control file size in gstreamer RTSPSRC if I just want one video file
I know how to record multiple videe files using multifiesink or splitmuxsink with the size limit from a RTSP stream, e.g an ONVIF camera.
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc -e location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=file%02d.mp4 max-size-time=100000 send-keyframe-requests= true

My application is required to record a 30-second video when triggered. I do not need multiple videos as it will consume more resource and delay other operations. Is there any way to control the size limit for the single video file?
The following creates one video file, but it continues to grow in size. I just need one(1) video file of 30 seconds.
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc -e location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! filesink location=Camera001.mp4 buffer-size=900

Basiccaly how do we use gstreamer to record one single video file of given size ( to say 30 seconds) from a RTSPSRC? Then it automatically stops after this file is recorded.

Really, just start writing a GStreamer application that does what you need.
